# How To Add Class To Style Search Box

Tags: menus, search, icon

I am not very experienced with PHP but have managed to find a snippet to add a search bar to my main menu, using this code in my functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box', 10, 2 );
function add_search_box( $items, $args ) {
$items .= '<li>' . get_search_form( 'echo=0' ) . '</li>';
return $items;
}
```

I don't know how to style this though, I know I need to add a class to it so I can style it with css but don't know how to! Also, I wondered how difficult it would be to make it just a search icon that toggles to a bar on click?  I think this can be done in css too?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Whats the source of the snippet? Please link to it.

Answer (score 0):

[The tutorial](http://bavotasan.com/2011/adding-a-search-bar-to-the-nav-menu-in-wordpress/) shows you how to add a class and style it.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box', 10, 2 );
function add_search_box( $items, $args ) {
$items .= '<li class="your-class">' . get_search_form( 'echo=0' ) . '</li>';
return $items;
}
```

For [CSS questions, please ask on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css).

But the code doesn't enable you to select between the primary or secondary nav menus unless you extend it like this.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items','wpsites_add_search_box', 10, 2 );
function wpsites_add_search_box( $items, $args ) {

if ( 'primary' != $args->theme_location )
return $items;

$items .= '<nav class="your-class">' . get_search_form( 'echo=0' ) . '</nav>';
return $items;
}
```

Written about this topic several times and i know you would want to use the same class as your themes nav menu if you want to style it the same.